# Why is my Safari download of Xcode over running?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, xcode

[image]

The picture says it all ("6.06 of 4.43"!?!). Never seen anything like it!
Shall I leave it, or re download?
What is the size meant to be of Xcode 8 Beta 3?

Comment: You didn't mention it but i'm assuming you're downloading this from the actual Apple Developer site and not a 3rd-part site.  If it's been running a long time, more than normal for Xcode downloads, I'd kill it, delete the file and try again. I've seen the Apple servers mess-up downloads of Xcode before.  Killing it and restarting has helped me with issues in the past.

Comment: This question actually made me laugh. Reminds me of those cheesy cartoons I used to watch when I was younger. I'm more questioning why it is in a XIP file rather than a ZIP.

Comment: The file format indeed looks rather unusual for Apple